# Parse PFCloud issues in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Ok, so this is my code:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getRates", withParameters: ["test": "test"], block: {
        (result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if ( error === nil) {
            NSLog("Rates: \(result) ")
        }
        else if (error != nil) {
            NSLog("error")
        }
    });
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Cannot invoke 'callFunctionInBackground' with an argument list of type 
'(String, withParameters: [String : String], block: (AnyObject!, NSError!) -> Void)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I copied your code into my project, but it compiles fine, both with the beta and the current stabil Xcode.

Comment: @DánielNagy I have the Parse framework added, and the bridging header set up woth Parse and Bolts. But For some reason anytime I need to add a block of code like the one above I get that same error...

Comment: Well I used Parse in a pure Swift project, without the bridging header.

Comment: So you just added the frameworks and then start coding? How were you able to use it without the Bridging header?

Comment: I just followed the instructions from this page: https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing .

Comment: But that is for an Objective-C app.. Thats not a guide for using swift.

Answer (score 4):

The error goes away if you plug in a NSMutableDictionary instance for the parameters instead of using Swift Dictionary literal.

Try:

```
let params = NSMutableDictionary()
params.setObject( "test", forKey: "test" )

PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getRates", withParameters: params, block: {
    (result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if ( error === nil) {
        NSLog("Rates: \(result) ")
    }
    else if (error != nil) {
        NSLog("error")
    }
});
```

I suppose the reason lies in the fact that NSDictionary is a Cocoa class, but Dictionary is a native Swift struct.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Swift 2.0. Similar error as mentioned by the original thread author... 

Cannot invoke 'callFunctionInBackground' with an argument list of type '(String, withParameters: NSMutableDictionary, block: (AnyObject!, NSError!) -> Void)'

Comment: This code works with one slight modification - you need to implicitly convert params by adding "as" right after params like so -  "withParameters: params as [NSObject : AnyObject])" for it to work with Swift 2.0

Answer (score 2):

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("funcNames", withParameters: params) {
    result, error in {
      yourCodehere
    }
}
```

As of Sept 2015, this code will work in new swift

Comment: Consider improving your answer: [Code only answers are considered of low-quality and are candidates for deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)